# Remove duplicates by key columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

In SAS, if I want to remove a sorted data with duplicates, I can use `proc sort` with `noduprecs` option. And `nodupkey` option can remove the duplicates by some key columns

e.g

```
proc sort data=HAVE out=WANT nodupkey;by var1, var2;run;
```

In SQL Server, I know `select distinct *` can produce something like `proc sort noduprecs`. But how to generate an output like what `proc sort nodupkey;by var1, var2` does in SAS?
(return the first value if duplicates exist)

**EDIT**

By using summary funtion like `max`, the duplicates can be removed while the maximum of those columns not specifed in a `group by` statement will be return.

```
select key1, max(var1) as var1, key2, key3, max(var2) as var2, max(var3) as var3
from #HAVE
group by key1, key2, key3
```

But what I want is to return the first combination of (var1,var2,var3).

Given

```
key1 var1 key2 key3 var2 var3
K1   20   K2   K3   30   BB
K1   10   K2   K3   40   AA
```

The ideal output is

```
key1 var1 key2 key3 var2 var3
K1   20   K2   K3   30   BB
```

not

```
key1 var1 key2 key3 var2 var3
K1   20   K2   K3   40   AA
```

Comment: Would a ***SELECT DISTINCT column1, column 2 FROM table*** work for you?

Comment: I don't need to include other columns in the `select` statement?

Comment: there is no such thing as the first combination of key1,key2,key3. This just makes no sense. Maybe if you have an autoincremental Id column or a timestamp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment you have a timestamp, using this timestamp it is possible to chose the "first" combinating of key1, key2 , key3

Here is a solution to pick the earliers dataset for each combination of key1, key2, key3

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 
  key1, var1, key2, key3, var2, var3, 
  row_number() over (partition by key1, key2, key3 order by timestamp) rn
FROM 
  #HAVE
)
SELECT 
  key1, var1, key2, key3, var2, var3
FROM
  CTE
WHERE
  rn = 1
```

Comment: I don't understand the syntax. Is `row_number()` a function? I don't have an existing column called `timestamp` in the data. Can I use any function to obtain the row index as `timestamp`? why `;with .. as ()`?

Comment: @GMTG you just wrote that you had data sorted by the timestamp. This cannot be solved, If you don't have a column to >order by<. The order the data is arranged in the table may not look random, but you can't rely on this sequence

Comment: Some of the SQL syntax used here (`row_number()`, `over` and `partition by`) is not supported within `proc sql` in SAS. It might work within a pass-through query to another dbms.

Comment: @user667489 I feel certain sas can call a stored procedure with this script